# How to access username information from within a CURL request?

Tags: python, django, curl

If I have the following curl request:

```
curl --dump-header - -H "Content-Type: application/json" -u TEST:TEST -X POST --data '{"alert": "[\"CPU\", \"Server\", \"Heartbeat\", \"Ping\"]", "id": 11, "pattern": ".*\\.websys\\.tmcs", "product": "TMOL", "pub_date": "2014-08-05 12:15:17", "resource_uri": "/tool/api/v1/sys_team/11/", "sys_team": "WebSys@xxxxxx.com","group":"WebSys"}' http://localhost:8000/tool/api/v1/sys_team/
```

Is there anyway I can get access to the -u information (specifically the username)? I can't use request.user.username because I want to authenticate the user based on the group he/she is in so it defaults to Anonymous user because it isn't authenticated yet.

Comment: You are asking this in what context? What is receiving the curl request?

Comment: It's worth learning how to dump out the raw requests—whether from within Django, or with flags to `curl`, or by setting up a fake server with `nc -kl 8000` to send requests to `localhost:8000`, or by Wiresharking the packets as they go over the wire, whatever's most comfortable for you. If you saw the headers in this case, it would have made the answer obvious.

Answer (score 1):

The command you wrote will send the TEST username and TEST password using the HTTP header Authorization.

```
Authorization: USERNAME THE_PASSWORD_USING_BASE64_ENCODING
```

You can read more about the Basic access authentication here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication